# Transpose Data Layout

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

[image: Table Result]

What would be the easiest way to format data from above image to below
My options available to be is either
1. Excel 
2. SSIS

I have made a SSIS package to read from various excel files and combine it onto a new result XLS file like the one above, but need to transpose some columns but at the same time need to duplicate the code part to concatenate to enable a unique row set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, I think the easiest way is to use `cross apply`:

```
select t.code, v.colname, concat(t.code, '-', v.colname), v.val
from t cross apply
     (values ([047], 'O47'), ([068], '068'), . . .
     ) v(val, colname);
```